# What is the proper way to introduce headers with TOKEN in a asynco aiohttp API request?

Tags: python, asynchronous, aiohttp

I need to download many different users data in a very slow API, so I decided to make parallel requests. After trying multithreads and multiprocess I decided asynco download would be the best in my case, and my code works for some cases I have tried without the header that includes the Bearer Auth... But in this case it gives  ClientConnectorCertificateError... Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import time

start_time = time.time()
headers =  {'accept': 'application/json','Authorization': "Bearer {}".format(token)}

async def get_cch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as resp:
        cch = await resp.json()
        x= cch['data']['contractId']
        return open(f'{x}.json', 'w').write(json.dumps(cch))


async def main():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:

        tasks = []
        for contract in range(len(file_name_list)):
            start_date = '2018-01-01'
            end_date = '2018-01-05'
            url = 'https://apinergia.somenergia.coop/cch/'+file_name_list[contract]+'?tariff=None&type=tg_cchfact&from_='+start_date+'&to_='+end_date+'&limit=30000'
            tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_cch(session, url)))

        original_cch = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for cch in original_cch:
            print(cch)

await main()

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html

Comment: Just add headers like in the requests library `headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer ASDasdqwp1231asd1231.asd123'}`

Comment: I have done it, it is in the example code, but it gives me an error that doesnt appear in urls without headers

Comment: @Ericp See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68891425/clientconnectorcertificateerror - the error you're referring to is probably an additional error, and it seems like you're passing the API key well

Answer (score 0):

Passing a bearer token is done just like passing any other header in aiohttp, using the `headers` parameter of the request. There is no special method/syntax to do this, unlike the case of `aiohttp.BasicAuth`. In this case, you're doing it correctly, by adding the `"Authorization": "Bearer <API_KEY>"` pair to the headers dictionary.

The errors you're experiencing are most probably unrelated to how you pass the token.

Answer (score -1):

something like this should work:

```py
class BearerAuth(aiohttp.BasicAuth):
    def __init__(self, token: str):
        self.token = token

    def encode(self) -> str:
        return f'Bearer: {self.token}'
```

Comment: As the `BearerAuth` is deriving from `BasicAuth`, it needs to satisfy its constructor. If you try to create an instance of this `BearerAuth`, you get this error:

`TypeError: BasicAuth.__new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'`

Comment: uh?
x = BearerAuth('test')


BearerAuth(login='test', password='', encoding='latin1')

Bearer: test