# gremlinpython submit async query returns ClientConnectorCertificateError in Django

Tags: django, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi, gremlinpython

I have a module that manages Azure Cosmosdb Gremlin queries. [When I call it from jupyter notebooks like this](https://github.com/BillmanH/exoplanets/blob/dev/notebooks/tests.ipynb), it works fine. However, when calling it from the Django app I get a ConnectionError:

```
Cannot connect to host graph-exodestiny.gremlin.cosmos.azure.com:443 ssl:True [SSLCertVerificationError: (1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)')]
```

Both the local jupyter notebook and the django app are importing the same module. That module's code is pretty simple gremlinpython stuff:

```
    ## Managing the client
    def open_client(self):
            self.c = client.Client(
                self.endpoint,
                "g",
                username=self.username,
                password=self.password,
                message_serializer=serializer.GraphSONSerializersV2d0(),
            )
            
    def close_client(self):
        self.c.close()

    ## Managing the queries
    def run_query(self, query="g.V().count()"):
        self.open_client()
        callback = self.c.submitAsync(query)
        res = callback.result().all().result()
        self.close_client()
        self.res = res
```

- Both are importing the same `cmdb_graph.py` connector module [here](https://github.com/BillmanH/exoplanets/blob/main/app/connectors/cmdb_graph.py).
- Both are running on the same [local environment](https://github.com/BillmanH/exoplanets/blob/dev/environment_local.yaml).

I also have the same application running here on an [Azure Web App](http://exodestiny.azurewebsites.net/) and it's working fine. From [this environment](https://github.com/BillmanH/exoplanets/blob/dev/requirements.txt).

The closest [related issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68891425/clientconnectorcertificateerror) is this one, however I'm unable to draw a connection. They seem to be totally different connector types.

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67976050/14457833)?

Comment: That's, interesting. But how to apply it to the `gremlinpython` library?  That post is about an ado pipeline.